# oracle 10g pl/sql conditional for loop select

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

Is it possible to do something like this in PL/SQL in 10g?

```
if user_is_goat = 1 then
  for item_rec in (select * from pricing_for_goats)
else 
  for item_rec in (select * from pricing_for_non_goats)
end if;
loop
.
.
end loop;
```

It seems that when oracle sees "for rec in select * from dual" it expects "loop" to immediate follow.  My code in the loop is many lines and I don't want to have to maintain 2 copies of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try query below, this will check if variable `user_is_goat = 1` and returns data from `for_goats` else it will return from `for_non_goats`

```
for item_rec in 
(
  select * from pricing_for_goats where user_is_goat = 1
  union
  select * from pricing_for_non_goats where user_is_goat <> 1
)
loop
.....
.....
end loop;
```

Comment: I like it, but will only work if the two tables are compatible

Comment: So can't you replace the * with the list of columns you need. You have to know what they are, since you're using them in the loop, right?